# Bounding box using MATLAB for the image

Tags: image-processing, matlab, bounding-box, matlab-figure

I am trying to draw a bounding box around the white blob in the image below:

[image]

I did like this:

```
bw = imread('box.jpg');
bw=im2bw(bw);
imshow(bw)
L = bwlabel(bw);
s = regionprops(L, 'Area', 'BoundingBox');
s(1);
area_values = [s.Area];
idx = find((100 <= area_values) & (area_values <= 1000)); % list of all the objects   

%whose area is between 100 and 1000

bw2 = ismember(L, idx); %construct a binary image containing all the objects whose 

%area is between 100 and 1000 by passing L and idx to ismember. 

imshow(bw2)
```

The output bw2, so far is: 
[image]

Can someone one tell me how to draw a bounding box around this blob(white)?

**Update**
Wajih's answer actually accurately solved the issue.

Comment: I treid this after the above code. But its not a good way of doing this:  imshow(bw2)

rectangle('Position', [ s(2).Centroid+35, 70, 100], 'EdgeColor','r')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pseduo -

- Pick largest y, largest x, smallest x, smallest y with in the blob. That is, points on the blob. These are your coordinates that you can use to build the bounding box.

assuming top left of image as (0,0)

```
(smallestX,smallestY)-----------------(largestX,smallestY)    
      |                                      |
      |                                      |          
      |                                      | 
      |                                      |
(smallestX,largestY)------------------(largestX,largestY)
```

And for finding minimum/maximum values and indices.

```
[r,c]=find(img==min(min(img)))
[r,c]=find(img==max(max(img)))
```

r,c represent row and column in the img matrix.

- I have marked the points on your  image that you can use to create the bounding box.
- Zoomed Image to get a better view.
  [image: Makred]
  [image: Zoomed]

Comment: Thanks you very much for your explanations. Can you tell me how do we pick largest y, largest x, smallest x, smallest y with in the blob?

Answer (score 3):

As the 20,000th viewer of this question, I'll answer what I think the asker is actually asking.

To render a rectangle on the page, you just need to properly interpret the bounding box for the shape.  You've already computed this in `s(idx).BoundingBox`

Thus, add these two lines to your script:

```
bb = s(idx).BoundingBox;
rectangle('Position',[bb(1) bb(2) bb(3) bb(4)],'EdgeColor','green');
```

and you'll get:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried regionprops from Image Toolbox?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to use **bwboundries**

```
boundaries = bwboundaries(blob);

numberOfBoundaries = size(boundaries);

for k = 1 : numberOfBoundaries

    thisBoundary = boundaries{k};

    plot(thisBoundary(:,2), thisBoundary(:,1), 'g', 'LineWidth', 2);

end
```