# find length and width of Circumscribed rectangle for a data set in 2d plane (Matlab)

Tags: matlab

Having a set of data in 2D (lets say knowing the position of some points in a plane), how could one find length and width of Circumscribed Rectangle for the points in Matlab?

Comment: You're searching for the [bounding box](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10140068/3022712)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bounding box using MATLAB for the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140068/bounding-box-using-matlab-for-the-image)

Comment: There is no image. I have some data set only @yar

Comment: Please describe the format of your data. I suppose you should be able to apply the provided method to your data, the accepted method does not use any image processing toolbox function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the bounding box using the maximum and minimum values of x and y coordinates. From these get the coordinates of the rectangle.

```
data = rand(10,2) ;
%% Get bounding box/ Rectangle
x0 = min(data(:,1)) ; x1 = max(data(:,1)) ;
y0 = min(data(:,2)) ; y1 = max(data(:,2)) ;
%% Legnth and breadth of rectangle
L = abs(x1-x0) ;
B = abs(y1-y0) ;
%% coordinates of rectangle 
Rect = [x0 y0 ; x0+L y0 ; x0+L y0+B ; x0 y0+B ; x0 y0] ;
%% figure
figure
hold on
plot(data(:,1),data(:,2),'.r')
hold on
plot(Rect(:,1),Rect(:,2),'b')
```

Comment: Is there a way to calculate the perimeter of the data set?

Comment: No, I don't mean it, I'm not so stupid! I mean perimeter which is built by connecting data points together

Comment: :) ..you mean the perimeter of the points given (Not the rectangle)?

Comment: Yes, exactly. :)

Answer (score 1):

To get the perimeter of the given points, you may proceed as below. First get the boundary points using *boundary*. Once you have boundary points, you can get the distances and sum them; which gives you perimeter.

```
data = rand(10,2) ;
%% Get boundary of the points
idx = boundary(data(:,1),data(:,2)) ;
%%
figure
hold on
plot(data(:,1),data(:,2),'.r') ;
plot(data(idx,1),data(idx,2),'b') ;
%% perimeter
bound = [data(idx,1) data(idx,2)] ;
dx_boundary = diff(bound) ;
dist = sqrt(dx_boundary(:,1).^2+dx_boundary(:,2).^2);
perimeter = sum(dist) ;
```

Comment: When I run above code, the result is Undefined function 'boundary' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Comment: What version are you on? boundary is introduced in 2014b....I think you are using a lower version.

Comment: 8.1.0.604 (R2013a) :(

Comment: How can I find these ways?

Comment: You can use _convhull_ instead of boundary.....but this one will over predict the perimeter then the _boundary_.